# Running part of bash script on a remote machine

Tags: bash, ssh

I need to run some commands locally and then some command on a remote machine all using a single local bash script.

For simplicity just say I want to do the following and execute it on my local desktop machine.

```
#!/bin/bash

#upload some files to a remote machine
cd /tmp
./upload-files.sh

#run commands on remote machine
ssh myuser:mypass@somewhere.com
cd /tmp/uploads    <--- these commands don't run in the ssh connection
./process-uploads.sh
exit

#run command locally again.
cd -
echo 'complete!'
```

Any ideas of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`here-doc`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) with `ssh` command:

```
#!/bin/bash

#upload some files to a remote machine
cd /tmp
./upload-files.sh

#run commands on remote machine
ssh -t -t myuser:mypass@somewhere.com<<EOF
cd /tmp/uploads
./process-uploads.sh
exit
EOF

#run command locally again.
cd -
echo 'complete!'
```

Comment: Do I need the double `-t -t`?

Comment: With single `-t` I got a warning **Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run only one command:

```
ssh myuser:mypass@somewhere.com 'cd /tmp/uploads; ./process-uploads.sh'
```